# Using 2 2GB RAM DIMMs with a single 4GB RAM DIMM

Tags: memory, motherboard

I bought 4GB RAM stick and I'm not sure which slot should I choose. I already had 2x2GB sticks on my motherboard installed. I'm not sure on which DIMM slot to put my new 4GB RAM stick. My motherboard model is ASUSTeK P7H55. The layout of the DIMM slots is: Black | Blue .. Black | Blue

So where do I put the 2x2GB RAM sticks and the 4GB stick for maximum performance since I found out that you should 'always' use even number of RAM sticks(because it's Dual Channel).

I tried a bunch of combinations and none showed the result I wanted. Using some combinations it showed that my computer had 4GB RAM, and using other it showed only 6GB.

Comment: You know full well where to insert RAM sticks. You might want to change the title to Computer isn't recognizing all 8GB of RAM

Comment: Where are you getting these results from? You also already answered your own question about best performance. Your board is dual channel if your not installing in pairs your not getting the best performance. Also give us more spec details on the RAM sticks

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the manual, the two channels, `A` and `B`, are each a pair of one blue and one black slot, `A` closer to the CPU socket and `B` farther away. Have you tried populating adjacent slots (ones in the same channel)?
The proper way to mix and match RAM capacities is to put the different sized sticks on different channels. The other thing to know is what speed are your different chips running at (ddr-3 has speeds from 1066 mhz to 1866+ mhz, and you should match these speeds across all channels). 
have you tried putting your 2 GB chips in the two closest slots to the CPU and the 4gb chip in the next one out?

When you boot into the bios (generally holding down the `delete` key while starting up), can you tell us what the system information screen says?